# Write a single byte to a file in python 3.x

Tags: python, file, stream, binary

In a previous Python 2 program, I used the following line for writing a single byte to a binary file:

```
self.output.write(chr(self.StartElementNew))
```

But since Python 3, you can't write strings and chars to a stream without encoding them to bytes first (which makes sense for proper multibyte char support)

Is there something such as byte(self.StartElementNew) now? And if possible, with Python 2 compatibility?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For values in the range 0-127, the following line will always produce the right type in Python 2 (`str`) and 3 (`bytes`):

```
chr(self.StartElementNew).encode('ascii')
```

This doesn't work for values in the range 128-255 because in Python 2, the `str.encode()` call includes an implicit `str.decode()` using ASCII as the codec, which will fail.

For bytes in the range 0-255, I'd define a separate function:

```
if sys.version_info.major >= 3:
    as_byte = lambda value: bytes([value])
else:
    as_byte = chr
```

then use that when writing single bytes:

```
self.output.write(as_byte(self.StartElementNew))
```

Alternatively, use the [`six` library](https://pythonhosted.org/six/), it has a [`six.int2byte()` function](https://pythonhosted.org/six/#six.int2byte); the library does the Python version test for you to provide you with a suitable version of the function:

```
self.output.write(six.int2byte(self.StartElementNew))
```

Comment: @galinette: Yup, not everything can be done with catching `ImportError` or `NameError` when writing polyglot code, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, which works with Python 2 and 3, is to use `struct`:

```
import struct
self.output.write(struct.pack('B', self.StartElementNew))
```